# Inheriting singals from child widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I created a Custom widget in QT, i use it in my main program but i cant use the signals from a QLineEdit, how can i do it?, this is mi code:

```
 search = new Search_browser(ui->widget);
 connect(search, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(set_page()));
```

Search_browser has a QLineEdit, that is why im trying to use `returnPressed()` signal, this should call a function in my MainWaindow to set a page but i get this error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal Search_browser::returnPressed()
```

Header file of the custom widget:

```
class Search_browser : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Search_browser(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~Search_browser();
        QString get_url();
    public slots:
        void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
        void get_request();

    private:
        QLineEdit *lineEdit;
        QCompleter *completer;
        QStringList wordList;
};
```

i think that i have to implement myself the signal but i dont know how.

Comment: Simply connect the signal from the QLineEdit to your own signal you defined in your Search_browser class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aggregate `QLineEdit` in `Search_browser` so now it's incapsulated (private), to make it accessable from outside world (from `MainWindow`) you can do one of two things: add accessor to it and connect to returned value.

```cpp
class Search_browser : public QWidget {
...
QLineEdit *getLineEdit() {return lineEdit;}
};

connect(search->getLineEdit(), SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(set_page()));
```

Or add signal to Search_browser and forward it.

```cpp
class Search_browser : public QWidget {
signals:
void returnPressed();
};

Search_browser::Search_browser() {
...
connect(lineEdit,SIGNAL(returnPressed()),this,SIGNAL(returnPressed()));
}
```